# Ubuntu mutes speaker every time I insert something in the phone jack

Tags: sound

Every time I insert something in my phone output jack, the sound is muted and I have to go into `alsamixer` and turn up the volume on the `Speaker` lever.

I can see the reason this is so - when I'm listening in phones, I don't want the laptop speakers on - but my hardware does this for me automatically, and the `Speaker` lever goes to the phone jack when something is inserted there. The result of alsamixer doing this adjustment is that I have to open a terminal, type `alsamixer`, find the speaker lever and turn it up again, *every time* I insert something in the phone jack.

There has to be a way to turn off this behavior. But how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem seems to be resovled out of the box in Ubuntu 12.04, without any (concious) action on my part. I guess that's a yay! =)

Answer (score 7):

I found a way to do this!

1. Start `alsamixer`:

   ```
   $ alsamixer
   ```
2. Hit <kbd>F5</kbd> to show all devices.
3. Scroll to the right until you find `Auto-Mute Mode`. Set it to `disabled`.

Done! My sound no longer mutes whenever I insert a plug in the phone jack!

Comment: It is possible that the package containing alsamixer has been updated since I first had this problem, if an update was published at the same time as many other updates - I usually don't read through the list too carefully if it's long :P This works with the version currently in the software repository for Ubuntu 11.10, though, so that shouldn't pose a problem for people finding this question in the future.

Comment: Turns out this wasn't so successful anyway: when I do this, the speakers on my laptop aren't muted at all. So now I can plug in something in my phone jack without having to go to alsamixer and turn the volume back up, but instead I have sound from both phones and speaker... =(

Answer (score 0):

Which sound card do you have? A [bug was reported](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/852915) recently.

Potential solutions/workarounds:

In your sound settings, try switching to analog speakers. It should look something like this:

[image: Analog]

Your other option would be to try the updated packages from the [alsa daily snapshots](https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-audio-dev/+archive/alsa-daily/+packages):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev/alsa-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

You will likely need to log out and back in, or perhaps reboot.

Comment: I was already on analog output (in fact, analog duplex). Switching to digital did not help, neither did switching back to analog...

Comment: And running the commands to upgrade alsamixer, no update was found.

Comment: What sound card do you have ?

Comment: Quite honestly, I don't know exactly how to find that out in Ubuntu. I'm quite new at this. I tried `sudo lshw` but it didn't give me anything. Where do I check?

Comment: can you run ` sudo lshw -c multimedia -sanitize | pastebinit` you may need to install pastebinit https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Pastebinit . Post the url back here

Comment: Nice! That was really useful =) [Here's my output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/770592/)

Comment: My only advice is to file a bug report, include the information from the pastebin and be sure to reference the bug report I gave you an that the ppa did not solve the problem.

Comment: [Bug filed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/904686). Since I suspect I will get no better answers, I'll mark this as accepted even though my problem is not resolved yet.

Comment: I subscribed to the bug report as well

Comment: I've got the same problem! Was this ever resolved?

Comment: @Pureferret: Yes, it seems it is resolved in Ubuntu 12.04 without any action from me =)